# How do I use a table alias in the formula when adding a field dimension to a table in Looker Studio

Tags: join, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have two name fields, one in the `orders` table and one in the `deliveries` table.

I am using a Big Query dataset connected to Looker Studio.

In the Blend, on the `orders` table, I am adding a calculated field to create a field that is 'TRUE' if the same name appears in two different fields and 'FALSE' if it is not.

`IF(shopper_name = deliveries.deliverer_name, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')`

I want to use this as a control field for filtering the chart, so I am using text, as booleans are not allowed as control fields, as far as I can tell.

Previously, these two name fields were available in the same table but are no longer. Before today I had created this field as a dimension on the table in the Blend, which made it available to both the control and the chart sections.

The problem I am having is the two name fields are on different tables now. I tried creating a custom dimension in the chart's properties, but it is not available to select as the control field in the control's properties.

I struggled to find documentation on this, but what I did find suggested I use `${deliveries.deliverer_name}` but Looker Studio says *Syntax error: Illegal input character "$"*

I am very new to Looker Studio, so I am not sure if what I am attempting is even possible.

Can I use an alias to reference another table when creating the formula for a field on a table in a blend?

If not, how can I create a field that is available to both the control and chart sections of the report?